# Getting mime type after file upload with Cloudinary

Tags: php, file-upload, mime-types, cloudinary

Consider uploading a file using Cloudinary PHP API:

```
\Cloudinary\Uploader::upload('http://www.example.com/image.jpg');
```

As stated [in the doumentation](http://cloudinary.com/documentation/php_image_upload), a basic response does not include the `mime-type` of the uploaded file:

```
Array
(
  [public_id] => c87hg9xfxrd4itiim3t0
  [version] => 1371995958
  [signature] => f8645b000be7d717599affc89a068157e4748276
  [width] => 864
  [height] => 576
  [format] => jpg
  [resource_type] => image
  [created_at] => 2013-06-23T13:59:18Z
  [bytes] => 120253
  [type] => upload
  [url] => http://res.cloudinary.com/demo/image/upload/v1371995958/c87hg9xfxrd4itiim3t0.jpg
  [secure_url] => https://res.cloudinary.com/demo/image/upload/v1371995958/c87hg9xfxrd4itiim3t0.jpg
)
```

Do I have to configure something in the settings to have it added to the response?

Comment: Can you please share some more information regarding why you need the mime-type in addition to the `format` that's already returned?

Answer (score 1):

Its never safe to check the mime type of something uploaded by someone else.
It can be faked easily.

If you only want to upload image (like in the exemple) the safest method is to re-process the image using GD or ImageMagick